# Why is the distance travelled by a non-skidding rolling object equal to the arc length?

Tags: rotation, rotational-kinematics

I'm having a hard time linking the rotational movement of a rolling object (like a tire) and the horizontal displacement in my head. Is there any way to prove that the distance travelled is exactly equal to the arc length of the rotation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's geometry. Suppose we wanted to find how much distance a wheel covers when it rotates. One way would be to lay down a piece of tape, sticky side up, in a straight line, and roll the wheel along its length. The tape wraps around the wheel as it travels, and the length of tape on the wheel is exactly equal to the distance traveled on the ground.

Answer (score 0):

Imagine instead of a rigid wheel, then you are rolling a yoyo. You hold on to the string at the starting point, and the yoyo rolls. It leaves the string as a trail.

The length of this trail is the traveled distance. But it is also the arc length (the rotational distance) traveled.